# Quarkus 3.3.1 when open localhost:8080/ quarkus is not open nice default 404 - resource not found page , getting forbiden

Tags: quarkus

thsi is the response

[image]

If I change the URL for my api like localhost:8080/hello, it works
if I use a wrong url like localhost:8080/hellou it doesn't open the nice default 404

Adding the pom dependencies

```
<dependencies>
    ...
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xerces/xercesImpl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>32.1.2-jre</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fathzer/javaluator -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fathzer</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaluator</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
    <version>1.16.0</version>
</dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.4</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
```

Could some of the above dependencies cause such behavior?

any help?

Comment: please share what you've got so we can help you. Did you add some kind of interceptor, or is it default quarkus starter ?

Comment: Hi @Jacouille, i updated with the dependencies that are not quarkus dependencies,
It is default quarkus starter